# Error: Failed to lookup view "home" in views directory

Tags: express, electron, electron-builder, electron-forge

I developed a small application with electron and expressjs. In development mode, the app works fine. But after  packaging the app for the production mode I got the error that the home view is not found. Here are some details:
The main route in app.js

```
router.get('/', async (req,res) => {
    res.render('home');
});
```

My file structure is:
[image]

In order to solve the problem I tried the following:

```
 router.get('/', async (req,res) => {
    var path = require('path');
    res.render(path.join(__dirname+'/views/home.ejs'));
});
```

Now the view is loaded, but all the css and js files within home.ejs are not loaded

[image]

All css and js files are located under the public folder and within home.ejs, i refer to these files as follows:

```
<script src="/js/vendor/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/vendor/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/home.js"></script>
```

I tried both electron packagers, electron-forge and electron-builder and had the same error. Can you please help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `express.static(...)` statement somewhere in your app to serve the css and js files. How does that look? The following should work:

```js
app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + "/public/js"));
app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + "/public/css"));
```